# Django 2.0: UpdateView creates a new object instead of updating

Tags: python, django

For some reason my UpdateView is creating new objects instead of updating existing ones. I've tried changing the URL parameter from `slug` to `pk` to no avail.

**models.py**

```
class EarthScienceEvents(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EarthScienceEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EarthScienceEvents
        fields = ['name']
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path("update/<slug:pk>", views.EarthScienceEventsUpdateView.as_view(), name="update"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class EarthScienceEventsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = EarthScienceEvents
    form_class = EarthScienceEventForm
    template_name = "earth_science_events/create_update.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('earth_science_events:list')
```

**create_update.html**

```
        <form action="" method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form | crispy }}
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
```

EDIT:

I've also tried doing this to explicitly define the URL being POSTed to:

```
<form action="{% url 'earth_science_events:update' object.slug %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

This hasn't fixed the issue.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: I think you do not properly filter, the slug field is - by default - in an `UpdateView` `slug`, so the path should be `path("update/<slug:slug>", ...`, or you should specify another `slug_field` in the view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I tried that but it's still doing the same thing. I am thinking about overriding `get_object` or `get_queryset` or something but shouldn't this work by default?

Comment: @AsishAcharya: the `slug_field` is by default set to `'slug'`, and should  do a proper filtering: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/ but the URL parameter thus should be named `slug` then, not `pk`.

Comment: Check which URL you are submitting the form from and which URL the request is posted to. If you have `<slug:pk>` then I would expect you to get an error saying the object does not exist, instead of it silently creating a new object. It sounds like you might be posting the request to your create view.

Comment: @Alasdair, Even when I completely comment out my create view, the UpdateView is still creating a new object. I've also tried explicitly adding the update view URL in the form's action, which didn't work either.

Comment: "didn't work either" isn't enough information to debug the problem. You need to show the exact code you are running and which URLs the requests are posted from/to.

Comment: @Alasdair, I'm POSTing from the URL `http://localhost:8000/earth-science-events/update/superb` where `superb` is the slug of the object i just created. The object is loading fine in the GET request (i.e. the form is already filled up with the initial value of `superb`). I'm POSTing to `{% url 'earth_science_events:update' object.slug %}`. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: What does `{% url 'earth_science_events:update' object.slug %}` appear as in the rendered template? Is that as expected? Could there be another URL pattern that is matching the request to `/earth-science-events/update/superb`?

Comment: I clicked `View Source` to check the HTML of the rendered page. It appears as `/earth-science-events/update/superb` which is expected. No, there is no other URL that could match since I have only one URL for the `/update/`.

Comment: I just spotted that you have `primary_key=True` for your slug field. That's unusual. You might avoid this issue if you use `slug = models.SlugField("Slug", unique=True)`, and let Django create an automatic primary key field.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try changing that.

Comment: @Alasdair, that worked! Thank you very much.